# View controllers present modally in storyboard, even while turned off

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, viewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

I have a problem in xcode which has been happening for while now, the problem is that even when I turn off the navigation bar in the navigation controller it still presents the view modally in the storyboard. like so:
[image]

so this fixes it in the simulator, you cant see the present modally or navigation bar, but in the story board it does. this makes it hard to set contraints and is an eye sore to me. the fix for this will be greatly appreciated! 
following images are 1, the present modally shown in the storyboard and 2, the present modally not showing in the simulator:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this happen consistently with a new project or storyboard?  I just added a navigation controller to a storyboard, set the root view controller as a new view controller and created a segue between that and another new view controller.  Both view controllers showed full screen presentation in Interface Builder.  Also, you may not want a segue between logout and login - you probably want to use an unwind segue if you will end up with an ever deeper series of view controllers in your navigation stack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it's an ios 13 thing and the default presentation style for xcode 11 is now `automatic`(previously `current context`). Just select the segue of that view controller in storyboard then go to `Attributes inspector` and you will find the `Presentation` with `automatic` as selected, simply change it to `Current context` and you're good. :)

Answer (score 2):

Follow this steps to solve your problem:

1. Select your **storyboard segue**
2. Go to "**Attributes inspector**" (right panel in xcode)
3. Change value of "**Presentation**" attribute to "**Current Context**"

In storyboard you'll found that the presenting layer is removed and the ViewController's View is occupying the whole screen.

[Look at the image here, it'll help you out easily and visually.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ocz3P.png)

Answer (score 1):

In case, if you don't find `Presentation` under `Attributes Inspector` of the segue, It can found under `View Controller` -> `Attributes Inspector`

Verified in `XCode` 12.4

Comment: IB changed in XCode 12+, so this is the correct solution now (XCode 14), but just to make it clear, it needs to be set on the source VC

Answer (score 0):

Set `Presentation` to `Current Context` and the VC will be shown in IB like the `NavigationController`